# FIlename output when partitioning on timestamp using PyArrow

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

I am currently using pyarrow to partition using a column called 'req_moment' to partition the data in a pyarrow dataframe. The partitioning process itself is okay, however the timestamp which is shown in the filename is polluted with different character (I think representing the white spaces and ":"). I am running the code below:

```
    pq.write_to_dataset(
        new_df.to_arrow(),
        f"abfss://{os.environ['STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONTAINER']}/{os.environ['STORAGE_ACCOUNT_PATH']}",
        partition_cols = ['req_moment']
        filesystem=fs,        
    )
```

This results in filenames which en like this:
`/req_moment=2023-12-15%2009%3A31%3A18/d2c327fa52dd4c1ebd6afdf8f4cea7fe-0.parquet`

The desired format is:
`/req_moment=2023-12-15 HH:mm:ss/d2c327fa52dd4c1ebd6afdf8f4cea7fe-0.parquet`

Is this possible or is it normal behavior?

I have tried converting the datatypes of the columns etc. but this all does not seem to help.

Comment: It looks like arrow is using URI encoding when converting the `:` in the timestamp string. I'm not sure there's a away to disable it. I can see a `segment_encoding` argument here https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.HivePartitioning.html but I don't think it is related.

Answer (score 0):

for each filename run unquote to get your actual text

```py
import urllib.parse
for filename in filenames:
    filename = urllib.parse.unquote(filename)
```